# Plot panda series in separate subplots using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas, plot, subplot

Hoping to get some help please, I'm trying plot simulation data in separate subplots using pandas and matplotlib my code so far is:

```
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import pandas as pd
fig, ax = plt.subplots(2, 3)
for i in range(2):
    for j in range(50, 101, 10):
        for e in range(3):
            Var=(700* j)/ 100
            Names1 = ['ig','M_GZ']
            Data1 = pd.read_csv('~/File/JTL_'+str(Var)+'/GZ.csv', names=Names1)
            ig = Data1['ig']
            M_GZ=Data1['M_GZ']
            MGZ = Data1[Data1.M_GZ != 0]
            ax[i, e].plot(MGZ['ig'][:4], MGZ['M_GZ'][:4], '--v', linewidth=1.75)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

But the code gives me 6 duplicate copies of the same plot:
[image]
instead of each iteration of `Var` having its own plot, I've tried changing the loop and using different variations like:

```
fig = plt.figure()
for i in range(1, 7):
      ax = fig.add_subplot(2, 3, i)
            for j in range(50, 101, 10):                
                     Var=(700* j)/ 100
                     Names1 = ['ig','M_GZ']
                     Data1 = pd.read_csv('~/File/JTL_'+str(Var)+'/GZ.csv', names=Names1)
                     ig = Data1['ig']
                     M_GZ=Data1['M_GZ']
                     MGZ = Data1[Data1.M_GZ != 0]
                     ax.plot(MGZ['ig'][:4], MGZ['M_GZ'][:4], '--v', linewidth=1.75)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

but that changes nothing I still get the same plot as above. Any help would be appreciated, I'm hoping that each subplot contains one set of data instead of all six

This is a [Link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/w0q77wk8rd3gyon/GZ_manual_method.csv?dl=0) to one of the Dataframes each subdirectory `~/File/JTL_'+str(Var)+'/` contains a copy of this file there are 6 in total

Comment: Can you show what Data1 (the data frame) looks like?

Comment: @user3645626 I've added a link to an example of how one of the Data frames would look like would that be enough or do you think all 6 would be more helpful?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in your loop

```
for i in range(2):  # Iterating rows of the plot
    for j in range(50, 101, 10): # Iterating your file names
        for e in range(3): # iterating the columns of the plot
```

The end result is that you iterate all the columns for **each file name**

For it two work, you should have only two nesting levels in your loop. Potential code (**updated**) :

```
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import pandas as pd
fig, ax = plt.subplots(2, 3)
for row in range(2):
    for col in range(3):
        f_index = range(50, 101, 10)[row+1 * col]
        print row, col, f_index
        Var=(700* f_index)/ 100
        Names1 = ['ig','M_GZ']
        Data1 = pd.read_csv('~/File/JTL_'+str(Var)+'/GZ.csv', names=Names1)
        ig = Data1['ig']
        M_GZ=Data1['M_GZ']
        MGZ = Data1[Data1.M_GZ != 0]
        ax[row, col].plot(MGZ['ig'][:4], MGZ['M_GZ'][:4], '--v',linewidth=1.75)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion but I keep getting `IndexError: index 3 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 3` however when i change the line `fig, ax` to `fig, ax = plt.subplots(2, 6)` a plot is produced where the top row is exactly the same as the bottom row, when `print row, col` is added I get `0,0 0,1 0,2 0,3 `instead the loop should be giving `0,0  0,1 0,2 1,0 1,1 1,2`

Comment: haha, sorry, i read too fast, for some reason i thought there was only 3 files. Have a look at the updated code.